# Python doesn't create a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.4. I have a program in witch I have two files:

```py
problems = open("out/problems.tex", 'w')
answers = open("out/answers.tex", 'w')
```

If I run this I get an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<encoding error>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 247-251:   character maps to <undefined>
```

If I run this:

```py
problems = open("out/problems.tex", 'w', encoding='utf8')
answers = open("out/answers.tex", 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

I get no errors but I also get no files 'problems.tex' and 'answers.tex'. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Here is my full program:

```py
from polygen import *

head_file = open("tex/head.tex", 'r', encoding="utf8")
ground_file = open("tex/ground.tex", 'r', encoding="utf8")

problems = open("out/problems.tex", 'w', encoding="utf8")
answers = open("out/answers.tex", 'w', encoding="utf8")

head = head_file.read()
problems.write(head)
answers.write(head)

t = polymult(7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)

problems.write(t[0])
answers.write(t[1])

ground = ground_file.read()
problems.write(ground)
answers.write(ground)

problems.close()
answers.close()
```

Comment: Does the folder 'out/' exist? What are you writing to the files that's generating the error in the first case?

Comment: Yes, folder 'out/' exists. I'm writing LaTeX code into files.

Comment: If I `mkdir out`, then execute `>>> problems = open("out/problems.tex","w",encoding="utf8")` in a python 3 shell, I get a zero-length file. Is the rest of your code doing something to remove the file?

Comment: What do you by "doing something to remove file"? I expect tat when there is no file 'problems.tex' in 'out' directory Python creates a zero-length file and then write there something. Now there is no file 'problems.tex' in 'out' directory and when I run this code the process finishing with exit code 0 but I have no my file there.

Comment: That's my expectation as well, and my experimental observation. Therefore, something's different between your environment and mine, and I'm trying to determine what. Your entire program is those two lines?

Comment: How are you running this. Are you running it from a script or interactively? Is the directory out under the directory that the script is in and that you are running it from?

Comment: Actually no. I have four files there and I'm writing a content of one file to 'problems.tex', then I'm writng a some strings my program has generated there and then I'm writing content of another file there.

Comment: I'm running this interactivetly using PyCharm. Directory 'out' is under  directory that the script is in.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I found that I was writing Russian text into not utf8 file - that was in 'head.tex' file.

Comment: @eryksun in error in the first example was occuring because of non-ASCII symbols in head.tex file. In the second example files actually created, but I didn't see that. That's my mistake. I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So weird. 2 suggestions:

1. Use an absolute path, make sure the file generated.
2. Use "rb"/"wb" mode instead "r"/"w" if you have non ASCii characters in source file